# post request not working, claims body data is not present when it is

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, nuxt.js, prisma

I am trying to update my table with a new row in prisma and i cant seem to find what the problem is.

my post looks like this:

```html
app.post(`/content`, async (req, res) => {
  const result = await prisma.content.create({
    data: {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
    },
  })
  res.json(result)
})
```

My model looks like this:

```html
model content {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  content String
}
```

I call my post like this:

```html
createContent() {
  let identifier = this.content.length + 1
  let newContent = { data: { id: identifier, title: 'Sample tekst', content: "Sample tekst" } }
  this.addContent(newContent.data)
      
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/content', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(newContent)
  })

  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error)
  })
}
```

I tried adding `id: req.body.id` to the data object in my post but it didnt make a difference.

Also tried removing id from the `newContent` object, still same error.

The error i get is:

```html
ERROR                                                                                                                                                       20:44:23
Invalid `prisma.content.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    id: undefined,
+   title: String,
+   content: String
  }
}

Argument title for data.title is missing.
Argument content for data.content is missing.

Note: Lines with + are required
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be title: req.body.data.title in your post method?

Comment: Tried that and now my console says:  ERROR  Cannot read property 'title' of undefined, not sure if that is progress

Comment: Firstly, `console.log()` whatever `request` you're getting in `req` at `app.post('/content', async (req, res) =>{})...`, also I can see in `createContent()` you're setting an `id`, but your primsa `id` variable is set to `@default(autoincrement())`, which means it's automatically created and incremented. Refer to [this documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model) in the `'Defining a default value'` under the `'Defining attributes'` tab.

Comment: the results of console logging req was too big to share so i made a video of it:
https://www.loom.com/share/57bba533953149899852e925a3752245

the id i use in createContent is not used by the post because like you said its not necessary although it is needed for my store in order to push a new object into the array so thats why i added it. I tried both adding id to my post and also removing id from the given object but neither seemed to make a difference same error in console is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. There's 2 ways of fixing this.

**Solution 1:**
Add headers.

```html
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/content', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(newContent),
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
})
```

**Solution 2:**

Install axios with `npm i axios`,like a real man then import it and make your post as following:

```html
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/products', newProduct)
  .then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
  .catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```